# react-native - TouchableWithoutFeedback with ScrollView

Tags: ios, react-native

Please help me with my problem. I have a long list of items, so I'm using ScrollView. But also I have Input field and using TouchableWithoutFeedback to make OnPress event to dismiss the keyboard, like that -

```
return (
     <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <View >
        <HeaderMain/>
        <ScrollView >
             ...
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

And my problem is that scrolling doesn't work. What should I do to make scrolling and dismissing keyboard both work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` and/or `keyboardDismissMode` props from ScrollView.

You can read more about that in the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html